# Android circular countdown

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, countdown, progress

I'm new to Android Development and I'm trying to build a circular progressbar. And in its center a text that will change whenever the progress will be reached. Can you provide some code example? See this example:  [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try https://github.com/diogobernardino/CircularCounter?

Another possible example: [Circular Progress Bar ( for a countdown timer )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010997/circular-progress-bar-for-a-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 0):

try this, https://github.com/uzairiqbal91/CircularTimerView  ,,this library has set of all functions and attributes required.