# Circle progress bar with countdown

Tags: android, progress-bar, countdowntimer

I have the following two programs [progress](http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/user-interface/form-widgets/progressbar), [countDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) that works but need to combine them to achieve what I want.Please see the image below.

I have the following issues.

1. Progress bar not smooth
2. Countdown time is going up and down and not counting down correctly

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   TextView tv2;
   ProgressBar pBar2;
   int pStatus = 0;
   private Handler handler = new Handler();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
       pBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

       new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              while (pStatus < 100) {
                   pStatus += 1;

                   handler.post(new Runnable() {

                       @Override
                       public void run() {

                           new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
                               @Override
                               public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                   pBar2.setProgress(pStatus);
                                   tv2.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                               }

                               @Override
                               public void onFinish() {
                                   tv2.setText("Go!");

                               }
                           }.start();
                       }
                   });
                   try {
                       // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                       // Just to display the progress slowly
                       Thread.sleep(200);
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
       }).start();
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: check this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010997/circular-progress-bar-for-a-countdown-timer).

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered a similar problem while developing a soccer Application and ended up writing my own View and overwriting onDraw and drawing Circles (Arcs) and writing a Text.

Going for this approach makes it much easier to control the View and not abuse ProgressBar to draw the Circle around - which even makes the View more lightweight.

[image]

In the right you can see the clock and the circles around drawing the state of the game.

So just go for a custom View and overrite the onDraw and manipulate the Canvas.

Good point to start learning this is here:

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html